# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop Folders not visible

Tags: 20.04

just a bold take. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I am using ubuntu since Ubuntu 18 LTS and currently I am facing a problem of not finding desktop apps on the GUI. It is available on the folder but from the desktop it ain't visible. Kindly help me out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEhMW.jpg)